# Update/Pre-populate the Room database inside github CI workflow/action

Tags: android, android-room

I want to pre-populate (the first time it runs) and to update (every other time) the database with the data that I'll fetch from another server that is running somewhere. After all of that I want to save the database into the asset folder and include it in the apk of an Android application.

This code is supposed to be called from workflow:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {

    val app = Application()
    val contentRepository = ContentRepository(catalogDatabase = AppModule.provideCatalogDatabase(app.applicationContext))
    val contentMetadataRepository = ContentMetadataRepository(
        catalogDatabase = AppModule.provideCatalogDatabase(app.applicationContext),
        repositorySetting = RepositorySetting()
    )
    val remoteContentService = AppModule.provideRemoteContentService()

    val catalogContentUpdater = CatalogContentUpdater(
        contentMetadataRepository = contentMetadataRepository,
        contentRepository = contentRepository,
        remoteContentService = remoteContentService
    )

    catalogContentUpdater.updateContentCatalog()

}
```

The RemoteContentService is a class which communicate with that server via ktor-client.

This is from the AppModule.kt

```
 @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideCatalogDatabase(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ): CatalogDatabase {
        return CatalogDatabase.initRoom(context)
    }
```

Also this is the database implementation. I am reading from asset file which later on I want to have as an updated db and include it in the apk.

```
abstract class CatalogDatabase : RoomDatabase(){
    abstract fun contentMetadataDao(): ContentMetadataDao
    abstract fun contentDao(): ContentDao


    companion object {
        fun initRoom(
            context: Context,
        ): CatalogDatabase {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                CatalogDatabase::class.java,
                "catalog_3"
            )
                .createFromAsset("catalog.db")
                .build()
        }
    }
}
```

this is the error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.content.Context.<init>(Context.java:23)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.<init>(ContextWrapper.java:23)
    at android.app.Application.<init>(Application.java:23)
    at com.t5qz8xf.util.pipeline.CatalogContentUpdaterKt$main$1.invokeSuspend(CatalogContentUpdater.kt:103)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:284)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.t5qz8xf.util.pipeline.CatalogContentUpdaterKt.main(CatalogContentUpdater.kt:101)
    at com.t5qz8xf.util.pipeline.CatalogContentUpdaterKt.main(CatalogContentUpdater.kt)
```

this is the script that is supposed to run this code and it's call inside .yml file

```
CATALOG_UPDATER_PATH="app/src/main/java/com/t5qz8xf/util/pipeline/CatalogContentUpdater.kt"

kotlin $CATALOG_UPDATER_PATH
```

```
      - name: Update Catalog Content from remote library
        run: scripts/update_catalog_content.sh
```

Also I am not sure if this is the right way to do this but neither I can move on or test anyhing until I resolve this.

The main problem is in Context but I can't initRoom without it.